# Controller method using JS doesn't return/render data when called within modal popup

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been stuck with this problem a couple of days, and I didn't find anything that could help me.

The idea is to get price_scenarios index view rendered in a modal popup. For each price_scenario shown in the table, a controller method, "price" is called. This method gets some info from the model and render it formated using JSON. This way of getting the prices was coded for a previous developer who is no longer in the project, and is necessary becouse price values can take a while to be calculated, so a small wheel gif is rendered when page loads.

The problem: price_scenarios "price" method doesn't render any value. This only happens if "price" is called within the index view rendered in a modal popup, I've tried doing this rendering price_scenarios index and it works fine. Also, this method is succesfully used in many other views of the app. I think it must be a problem with format responses, due to call the method from a popup, but everything I've tried haven't improved the results.

**product show.html.haml** a button displaying price_scenarios index as a modal popup:

```
 %h3
   = model_class.human_attribute_name(:price)
   = link_to PriceScenario.model_name.human(count: 2), formula_product_price_scenarios_path(@formula, @product), remote: true, data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#price_scenarios"}, class: "btn"

 #price_scenarios(class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Delta" aria-hidden="true")
```

**price_scenarios_controller.rb** definition of index and price methods

```
class PriceScenariosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_client
  load_and_authorize_resource :formula
  load_and_authorize_resource :product, :through => :formula
  before_filter :get_tuple, only: :price

  def index
    @price_scenarios = @product.price_scenarios
    respond_to :js
  end

  def price
    @price_scenario = PriceScenario.find(params[:id])
    @price = @price_scenario.shifted_price(@tuple)
    @price_units = @product.price_units

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render partial: 'price'}
      format.json { render json: {price: @price, units: @price_units}}
    end
  end
```

**price_scenario index.js.haml view** renders index view in the modal:

```
$("#price_scenarios").html("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'modal_price_scenarios')}");
```

**_modal_price_scenarios.html.haml** view rendered in the modal, "price" is called within it.

```
#modal_price_scenarios(class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Delta" aria-hidden="true")

  - model_class = PriceScenario

  .modal-body
    %table.table.table-striped
      %thead
        %tr
          %th= model_class.model_name.human
          %th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:price)
          %th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:references)
      %tbody
        - @price_scenarios.each do |scenario|
          %tr
            %td= scenario.name
            %td.price{:"data-product-price" => price_formula_product_price_scenario_path(@formula, @product, scenario)}
              = image_tag('ajax-loader.gif')
```

**-Price.html.haml partial** rendered by price_scenarios price method.

```
= "#{@price} #{@price_units}"
```

**product_price.js**

```
$(function(){
  $('[data-product-price]').each(function(){
    var url = $(this).data('product-price')
    $.ajax({
      url:      url,
      cache:    false,
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function( data ) {
        var priceWithUnits = data['price'] + ' ' + data['units']
        $('[data-product-price="' + url + '"]').html(priceWithUnits);
      });
  });
});
```

Browser console and development log don't show any error, but it seems that proper requests are not being done. Launching a manual request via HttpRequester produces the right result.

**Browser console** after showing the modal:

```
GET localhost:3000/es/formulas/84/products/69/price_scenarios [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1590ms] 
POST http://localhost:3000/mini-profiler-resources/results [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 154ms]
```

**Development log**

```
Rendered price_scenarios/_modal_price_scenarios.html.haml (1537.1ms)
Rendered price_scenarios/index.js.haml (1542.6ms)
```

**Manual request**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/es/formulas/84/products/69/price_scenarios/20/price?_=1427‌​711855278 -- response -- 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private, max-age=0 X-Request-Id: af912de9ef3e953387ddbd5f687aa1c2 X-Runtime: 2.647176 X-Miniprofiler-Ids: ["yxomxau7wdgouexw439j"] Content-Length: 18 Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2014-02-24) Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2015 11:04:41 GMT Connection: Keep-Alive 275.391 EUR / MWh
```

Comment: what does sending a `dataType: JSON` request to `price_formula_product_price_scenario_path(@formula, @product, scenario)` give you? Have you checked the browser console - any errors? Also check the logs if Rails chokes up on the JSON request.

Comment: @papirtiger
Checking Browser console when modal is displayed produces:
GET http://localhost:3000/es/formulas/84/products/69/price_scenarios `[HTTP/1.1 200 OK  1590ms]
POST http://localhost:3000/mini-profiler-resources/results [HTTP/1.1 200 OK  154ms]` NO errors, But it doesn't seems that price requests are being made al all.
Development log and server console also show no errors, neither GET price requests:
  `Rendered price_scenarios/_modal_price_scenarios.html.haml (1537.1ms)
  Rendered price_scenarios/index.js.haml (1542.6ms)`

Comment: @papirtiger 
Strange, when called from the same index view, but nor rendered as modal popup, price procedures produces following request:

`Started GET "/es/formulas/84/products/69/price_scenarios/20/price?_=1427711855278" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-30 12:37:38 +0200
Processing by PriceScenariosController#price as JSON`

And it works properly.

Comment: @papirtiger I've used HttpRequester to make the request you asked for, with the following results:
`GET http://localhost:3000/es/formulas/84/products/69/price_scenarios/20/price?_=1427711855278

 -- response --
200 OK 
Content-Type:  text/html; charset=utf-8
X-UA-Compatible:  IE=Edge
Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
X-Request-Id:  af912de9ef3e953387ddbd5f687aa1c2
X-Runtime:  2.647176
X-Miniprofiler-Ids:  ["yxomxau7wdgouexw439j"]
Content-Length:  18
Server:  WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2014-02-24)
Date:  Mon, 30 Mar 2015 11:04:41 GMT
Connection:  Keep-Alive

275.391 EUR / MWh`

Answer (score 1):

> Rendering JSON sets the content type to application/json and
>   optionally wraps the JSON in a callback. It is expected that the
>   response will be parsed (or eval’d) for use as a data structure.
>   http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render

However it does not actually convert hashes to a JSON encoded string which you need to do manually:

```
format.json { render json: {price: @price, units: @price_units}.to_json }
```

I find [ActiveModel Serializers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html) really useful for building JSON response objects which can quickly get out of hand if you are doing anything complex.

```
class PriceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :price_units
  attributes :name, :whatever
end

class PriceScenariosController < ApplicationController
  #...
  def price 
    # ...
    format.json { render json: @price }
  end
end
```

**Edit**
Another issue which if you modal may not actually been added to the DOM when `product_price.js` is run.

```
// Not guaranteed to have run before product_price.js
$("#price_scenarios").html("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'modal_price_scenarios')}");
```

Possible solutions are to add the partial in a hidden element instead of as a javascript string or using `<template>` elements.

Comment: Sorry, didn't worked. Price method is used in other views and works fine, so it seems to me that the problem could be caused by the GET requests being made with incorrect format type, or not being made at all?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it works in your other views because you are requesting and recieving a `text/html` format (which you also seem to have requested).  Your AJAX request uses the correct `dataType` - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Edit - added other possible explanation

Comment: This last idea seems a really good point. Could you please explain a little bit more how to solve it? Can an action be rendered as a partial?

Comment: I can now confirm that the cause is modal not being in DOM when product_price.js is run, I tried
`$(document).on('shown.bs.modal',function (){
  productPrice();
});` 

And it worked! I need further checking the whole idea, as this fix appears to cause some other features in the modal don't work properly, but it seems the right direction. Thanks a lot.